# Saving a NSImage to disk on a sandbox app in cocoa - CRASH

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, entitlements, nssavepanel

I have this NSImage I want to save to disk on a sandbox app.

I have this code:

```
- (void)exportPNGImage:(NSImage *)image withName:(NSString*)name
{

  NSArray *windows =[[NSApplication sharedApplication] windows];
  NSWindow *window = windows[0];

  // Build a new name for the file using the current name and
  // the filename extension associated with the specified UTI.
  CFStringRef newExtension = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(kUTTypePNG,
                                                             kUTTagClassFilenameExtension);
  NSString* newName = [[name stringByDeletingPathExtension]
                       stringByAppendingPathExtension:(__bridge NSString*)newExtension];

  NSSavePanel *panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
  [panel setNameFieldStringValue:newName];
  [panel setAllowsOtherFileTypes:NO];
  [panel setAllowedFileTypes:@[(__bridge NSString*)newExtension]];

  [panel beginSheetModalForWindow:window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
    {
      NSURL *fileURL = [panel URL];

      // Write the contents in the new format.
      NSBitmapImageRep *imgRep = [[image representations] objectAtIndex: 0];
      NSData *data = [imgRep representationUsingType: NSPNGFileType properties: nil];
      [data writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];

    }
  }];

}
```

CRASH: **an error occurred while attempting to connect to listener 'com.apple.view-bridge': Connection interrupted - Assertion failure in +[NSXPCSharedListener connectionForListenerNamed:fromServiceNamed:], /SourceCache/ViewBridge/ViewBridge-99/NSXPCSharedListener.m:394] NSXPCSharedListener unable to create endpoint for listener named com.apple.view-bridge**

here are the entitlements:

[image]

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10719948/316469) without success.

Comment: Make sure you call exportPNGImage: from main thread. Also why are you adding the sheet to windows[0] and not mainWindow? How do you make sure windows[0] is the correct one?

Comment: the crash is on the line `NSSavePanel *panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];`. The panel cannot be used on sandboxed apps with storyboards. Have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[NSSavePanel savePanel];
```

and

```
[NSSavePanel openPanel];
```

simply don't work on OSX 10.10, 10.10.1 and 10.10.2 on storyboard apps.

The solution given by Apple to me was "use Xibs".

After having a long list of problems with storyboard apps on OSX, I don't use them anymore. "Use XIBS" is what I am doing.

Comment: How do you use XIBS?

Comment: You cannot do it anymore on Xcode 9. You have to get an old version of Xcode, probably Xcode 7 and start a new project using XIBs there... or create it manually...